# How to calculate sum in java?

Tags: java

I need to write a code where you insert 10 grades and get back the average of those ten grades. I know how to do it, except I don't know how to calculate the sum of all the grades. I found on this site this code:

```
public int sumAll(int... nums) { //var-args to let the caller pass an arbitrary number of int

int sum = 0; //start with 0

    for(int n : nums) { //this won't execute if no argument is passed
        sum += n; // this will repeat for all the arguments
    }
    return sum; //return the sum
}
```

so I wrote my code like this and it worked!:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loop7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter how many grades you want to insert : ");
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
        int num;
        double sum =0;
        for(int i= 0; i<num1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade: ");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            sum += num;
        }
        System.out.println("the average is: "+(sum)/num1);

    }
```

so my question is what sum+=num; mean? how does that line give me the sum? and why I had to write double sum= 0?

Comment: You mention javascript but this is all java. There's a huge difference between the two. I'd start by nailing down which language you're using.

Comment: `sum += num` means `sum = sum + num`.

Comment: As a side note, you really need to research before asking. A google search for `java +=` reveals numerous resources which answer at least one of your questions. If you want to know why you need `double sum= 0;` try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: ok got it about the javascript thank you. i googled java += and I understood what it means, i dont understand how sum+num give me the sum of the grades I insert?

Comment: [Java Language Basics: Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: `sum += num` adds the value of  `num` to the current value of  `sum` in the variable `sum`.

Comment: I'm sensing you're lacking some java fundamentals. I mean, the loop is literally just adding each number that you enter to `sum`. It really doesn't get more basic than that. Please pick up an introductory tutorial or book.

Comment: so if sum= 0 why do i need to use it if the value of num is added to sum? and how do i know the value of num is the sum of all the numbers I insert and not just the last number, or one of the numbers?

Comment: Because you can't reference variables that don't exist. You have to declare `sum` before you can do anything with it. I'm not sure how to answer your second question. You know because that's what the code does. Run it and find out for yourself. This kind of ties into my previous comment. This is extremely basic java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over here I explain each of those lines to better help you understand this code.

```
public class Loop7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); //this is what allows the user to input their data from the console screen
        System.out.println("Please enter how many grades you want to insert : "); //this just outputs a message onto the console screen
        int num1 = scan.nextInt(); //This is the total number of grades the user provides and is saved in the variable named num1
        int num; //just a variable with nothing in it (null)
        double sum =0; //this variable is to hold the total sum of all those grades
        for(int i= 0; i<num1; i++) //loops as many times as num1 (if num1 is 3 then it loops 3 times)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade: "); //output message
            num = scan.nextInt(); //every time the loop body executes it reads in a number and saves it in the variable num
            sum += num; //num is then added onto sum (sum starts at 0 but when you add 3 sum is now 3 then next time when you add 1 sum is now 4 and so on)
        }
        System.out.println("the average is: "+(sum)/num1); //to get the average of a bunch of numbers you must add all of them together (which is what the loop is doing) and then you divide it by the number of items (which is what is being done here)  

    }
```

Comment: sum += num simply means you are adding num to whatever sum is at the moment. Don't confuse this with REPLACING sum with num which is totally different

Answer (score 0):

`sum += num;` Means that your `sum` which is declared 0 is added  with `num` which you get from the console. So you simply make this: `sum=sum+num;` for the cycle. For example sum is 0, then you add 5 and it becomes `sum=0+5`, then you add 6 and it becomes `sum = 5 + 6` and so on. And it is double because you are using division.

Comment: ok got it thank you. so do i have to add the sum variable? i cant just write the code without it and at the end write System.out.println("the average is: "+num/num1); ?

Comment: no, you can't every time you enter the cycle  num gets a new value: num = scan.nextInt(); so the old value is lost. Therefore you have to have a third variable to store the values. It wolud be nice if you upvoted my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

The reason you needed to write

```
double sum = 0.0;
```

is because you needed to initialize the sum first. Next the

```
sum += num;
```

means

```
sum = sum + num;
```

just in a more simple way.

Comment: Hope this clarifies. I tried to keep it in most simple terms.